# Using creation and annihilation operators to prove the expression for the $n$th excited state in terms of the vacuum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator

> How does one prove that the $n^{th}$ excited state of a quantum harmonic oscillator (QHO) can be obtained by applying the creation operator $a^{\dagger}$ $n$-times to the vacuum state $\vert 0\rangle$? i.e. how does one prove that $$\vert n\rangle=\frac{\left(a^{\dagger}\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\vert 0\rangle~?$$

I have started by noting that $\left[a,a^{\dagger}\right]=1$ and $N\vert n\rangle =n\vert n\rangle$ (where $N=a^{\dagger}a$ is the *number operator*). Then $$\langle n\vert aa^{\dagger}\vert n\rangle =\langle n\vert \left[a,a^{\dagger}\right]+a^{\dagger}a\vert n\rangle = \langle n\vert 1+N \vert n\rangle= \langle n\vert n\rangle +\langle n\vert N \vert n\rangle =1+n.$$

This then implies that $$a^{\dagger}\vert n\rangle =\sqrt{n+1}\vert n+1\rangle.$$

This is where I get stuck however, as the only way I can see (at the moment) is to repeatedly apply this relation to the ground state, but this feels a little unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

> Repeatedly applying this relation to the ground state

is exactly what you need to do. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: Ah ok, so that's valid then to derive the expression - I really was unsure whether it was ok to do this or not?!

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly valid.